# Swift/iOS: How to access Object properties when type-casted from Protocol?

Tags: swift, core-data, protocols, generic-programming, swift-protocols

**Some context first:**
I am building a generic API for my CoreData Database. All Objects in my model live in pairs:

- An NSManagedObject class that is stored in CoreData and can be converted into an NSObject with a protocol called `ManagedObjectProtocol`
- An NSObject class that is actually used throughout my app and can be converted into an NSManagedObject with a protocol called `DataObject`

My ManagedObject Protocol

```
//MANAGED OBJECT PROTOCOL - Should be adhered to by all NSManagedObject classes
protocol ManagedObjectProtocol where Self: NSManagedObject {
    //var managedObjectID: NSManagedObjectID { get set }

    func populateRegularObject() -> DataObject
    func populateRegularObjectFromRelated<T: TypeErasedDataObject>(relatedObject: T, at key: String) -> DataObject
}
```

In my API, I load the objects as follows:

```
let managedObject = API.shared.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext().object(with: someObjectID) as! ManagedObjectProtocol
let toReturn = managedObject.populateRegulardObject() //<-- This Crashes
```

**The problem:**
This successfully loads my object. I should now be able to populate the DataObject that belongs to this ManagedObjectProtocol and use it in my app. But I can't because, apparently, typecasting to a Protocol loads the object differently than when I TypeCast it as a normal `NSManagedObject`. Immediately when I access a property of the loaded ManagedObject, my app crashes with error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

**Question**:
How can I access my NSManagedObject's properties when I *need* to typecast it to a protocol?

To me, it would make sense to be able to do something like this:

```
extension NSManagedObject where Self: ManagedObjectProtocol {
    func populateDataObject() -> DataObject
}
```

But this can't be done in swift. Can anyone suggest a solution? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: could you provide code of `object(with:) -> NSManagedObject` method?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? It's hard to guess why your code crashes without having a bigger picture of the actual code.

Comment: As @Cristik said, you should post the actual code or enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I added some basic code. The problem here really lies in accessing an object's variables when it's typecasted to the protocol it adheres to.

Answer (score 3):

The following post will help you better understand the issue

https://www.lesstroud.com/dynamic-dispatch-with-nsmanaged-in-swift/

Essentially, it seems that core data is unable to handle protocols which are unmanaged. It seems like core data rewrites the class definition to pass @NSManaged through proxy methods, but is unable to do so for protocols.

Adding the `dynamic` keyword to your property declaration will solve this issue.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the solution you're offering, but it does not solve my issue. The error stays the same. I have added some more code to provide you with some more insight. I actually don't think this is tied to NSManagedObject as I also experience it with other objects. the problem seems generic to accessing any objects properties while it's type casted to the protocol it adheres to. Would you have any other idea?